# How to set ringtone from raw folder file

Tags: android, ringtone

I tried the below code but it sets default ringtone.

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackagename/"+R.raw.sound);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,  path);
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270520/1276374 `Barons` comment

Comment: i already tried the above link but not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168402/setting-ringtone-from-my-raw-folder-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/"+R.raw.xxx);
```